# How should vulnerable code be marked?

Tags: feature-request, code-vulnerabilities

So many code vulnerabilities originate from Stack Overflow. I see these issues as part of my daily work reviewing code.

Here are just a few sources discussing it:

- [Take care copy-and-pasting that code from Stack Overflow](https://www.grahamcluley.com/take-care-copy-pasting-code-stack-overflow/)
- [Stack Overflow Considered Harmful? The Impact of Copy&Paste on
  Android Application Security](https://www.aisec.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/aisec/Dokumente/Publikationen/Studien_TechReports/englisch/stackoverflow.pdf)
- [Watch Out For Insecure Stack Overflow Answers!](https://www.attackflow.com/Blog/StackOverflow)

Stack Overflow is obviously not the only seeder of vulnerable code, as found recently by researchers:
[Leveraging Flawed Tutorials for Seeding Large-Scale Web Vulnerability Discovery](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02786)

So how should it be handled? I have three suggestions:

---

1. Do not let anyone post copyable vulnerable code.

   - If someone posts code that is known to be vulnerable, it should be in a form of a picture instead of copyable text.
   - If a reviewer spots vulnerable code, it should be replaced by a picture of the code or flagged to be replaced.

Instead of:

```java
String user = request.getParameter('user');
String query = 'SELECT * FROM  Users where userName='' + user + ''';
```

Use:
[image: Vulnerable code]

---

2. Make it hard to copy by (for example) using it in a `onContextMenu="return false"` paragraph.

---

3. Wrap it in a red frame

Comment: What about fixing insecure code instead of making it hard to copy? The same harm is done when users retype code from images without thinking.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that, if we start flagging vulnerable code in big bold highlights, users may see undiscovered vulnerable code and assume it's safe as it is not marked as dangerous.  While I will highlight any security issues that I might see, it is ultimately up to the end user how they use the answers on this site, and we cannot be responsible for their lack of judgment.

Comment: @BDL, If you can fix it that is great, go right ahead! If you can't, or don't have the time, maybe just flagging it as vulnerable will help someone. Regarding retyping code, I don't think we should bullet proof it, just make it a little harder to instinctively copy-paste.

Comment: Relevant: [Automatically mark questions with SQL injections vulnerabilities](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339093),

Comment: It's not up to us to decide what is and is not "secure", and generally laying on a bunch of input/output sanitizing code only clutters up code samples and obscures the actual answer.

Comment: @meagar It's *absolutely* up to users of the site to evaluate the quality of answers, and having security vulnerabilities is *certainly* a factor in the quality of an answer.  Additionally, manually sanitizing input/output is almost always the wrong approach, fortunately *safe* approaches tend to be *clearer* than the unsafe counterparts, not obscured, as it simply comes down to using the correct tools already available, rather than trying to roll your own and doing it wrong.

Answer (score 18):

> it should be in a form of a picture instead of copyable text.

**No, absolutely not.** It's bad enough getting screenshots of text and images with either no alt text at all or alt-text that's absolutely useless in questions. We should not be deliberately making code inaccessible and invisible to users who can't see images in answers as well.

> Make it hard to copy

There's always a way around that sort of thing.

But the other problem with both the 1st and 2nd suggestion is that they doesn't address the issue of people using code that has security problems at all. If the person using the vulnerable code has to spend a couple of minutes re-typing it instead of 2 seconds to copy it, what's actually changed? Nothing, because the user still has no idea that the code has problems.

> Wrap it in a red frame or background and add a clear warning.

I'm not on board with adding a border or background. The site already fades out highly down voted answers (and IIRC, red is used for deleted answers). Adding a border or background would imply that the system and/or community itself is saying that there's an issue with the post instead of the one user who caught the problem.

Adding a warning to the answer itself could be seen as an attempt to reply. It's also putting words in the answerer's mouth; you don't know that they agree that there's an issue with their code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the role of the SO community is to provide guidance *depending upon what the question asks*.  As such, what a person does with that code is upto him.  If that code results in bugs when released in production, it is not the responsibility of the SO community!

Also, if you spot some vulnerable code, then the best course of action is to edit it and update it to remove the vulnerability.

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph, but not the second. You can comment on the vulnerability, but if you edit it out, I would reject that suggested edit.

Comment: What about code that is purposefully vulnerable to educate or to explain? Would you also fix that?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: "*if you edit it out, I would reject that suggested edit.*" I wouldn't. If someone writes some code that has an obvious, easily fixed bug (regardless of what that bug is), where fixing it doesn't change the intent of the solution, there's no reason not to allow it to be edited in. If the fix requires a major rewrite or algorithmic change, then that needs to be discussed with the author, but that's true of any major rewrite. My point being that fixing a vulnerability would not be a reason to reject a code change.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that there is something that needs to be done. Having seen multiple examples of vulnerable code this week makes me wonder, why Stack Overflow is helping the disease to spread. I'd rather have it become a platform to fight bad code and improve the application security worldwide.

I wouldn't like to prevent copy/paste, as this is a mechanism that helps the reviewers and the people answering the questions too, but I would like to propose following (warning, draft ahead):

1. We need a way of flagging the code/the question containing the code as vulnerable.
2. We need a mechanism similar to review to agree upon it being vulnerable.
3. We need to put the post into review again after changes have been made.

The details would need to be discussed and agreed upon, but right now let's agree upon just one thing. There is a problem with bad code being spread with Stack Overflow worldwide.

Thank you for not deleting the question despite it being downvoted badly.